# An improper integral with parameter $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I have to analyse the convergence of this integral:

$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$ where $p\in \mathbb{R}$.

I have thought to write:

$$\int_{1}^{c}\frac{\ln(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+\int_{c}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

For the second integral, I know that $\frac{\ln(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}<\frac{(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ so I can study the second one:

if p>0:

$1+x^p\sim x^p$, $\sqrt{x^2-1}\sim x$, so I obtain: $\frac{(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\sim \frac{1}{x^{1-p}}$ that converges if p<0. But I have said that p must be >0, so I don't obtain solutions.

If p<0 the intergral function that I use to compare it with the mine, diverges. So, for the theorem on asymptotic comparision, my integral diverges.

But I don't know how to bring out something about the first integral....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $p \in \mathbb{R}$. Let's consider three cases.

- $\color{blue}{\text{Case 1.}}$  $\quad p> 0.$

  We have, as $x \to +\infty$,

$$
\frac{\ln(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} \sim p\frac{\ln x}{x}
$$

and the initial integral is **divergent** by comparison to the divergent integral $\displaystyle \int_b^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x} dx \quad (b>0).$

- $\color{blue}{\text{Case 2.}}$  $\quad p=0.$

  We have, as $x \to +\infty$,

$$
\frac{\ln(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} \sim \frac{\ln 2}{x}
$$

and the initial integral is **divergent** by comparison to the divergent integral $\displaystyle \int_b^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx \quad (b>0).$

- $\color{blue}{\text{Case 3.}}$  $\quad p<0.$

  We have, as $x \to +\infty$,

$$
\ln(1+x^p) \sim \frac1{x^{|p|}}
$$
$$
\frac{\ln(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} \sim \frac1{x^{|p|+1}}
$$

and $\displaystyle \int_b^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx \quad (b>0)$ is **convergent** by comparison to the convergent integral $\displaystyle \int_b^{\infty} \frac1{x^{|p|+1}} dx.$

We have, as $x \to 1^+$,

$$
\frac{\ln(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} \sim \frac{\ln 2}{\sqrt{2} }\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}
$$

and $\displaystyle \int_1^{a} \frac{\ln(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx \quad (a \to 1^+)$ is **convergent** by comparison to the convergent integral $\displaystyle \int_1^{a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}} dx.$

> Thus your initial integral is **convergent if and only if** $p<0$.

Comment: I'm so grateful to you! Your answer is splendidly clear and "tidy"!! Have a good day!

Comment: @sunrise Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a little clarification.. I haven't understood in which way you have obtained $\sqrt{x^2-1} \sim \sqrt 2 (\sqrt{x-1})$.. I have tried with "ordinary" expansion in series but I haven't obtained this result.. can you explain me? A lot of thanks again!

Comment: @sunrise As $x \to 1^+$, we may write $ \displaystyle \sqrt{x^2-1} = \sqrt{x+1} \times \sqrt{x-1} \sim \sqrt{1+1} \times \sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{2} \times \sqrt{x-1}$. Hoping it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For any **$p\ge 0$**, we have

$$\frac{\log(1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\ge \frac{\log 2}{x}.$$

> Thus, the integral diverges for $p\ge 0$.

---

For **$p<0$**, we can write $\log(1+x^p)=\log(1+x^{-|p|})=\log \left(\frac{x^{|p|}+1}{x^{|p|}}\right)=\log(1+x^{|p|})-\log(x^{|p|})$.  Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{\log (1+x^p)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right|&=\frac{\log(1+x^{|p|})-\log(x^{|p|})}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,\int_{x^{|p|}}^{1+x^{|p|}}\frac{dt}{t}\\\\
&\le \frac{2}{x^{|p|+1}}
\end{align}$$

for $x>2\sqrt{3}/3$.  We can see this since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^{-2}}}\le \frac1x \times 2$ for $x>2\sqrt{3}/3$.

> Thus the integral converges for all $p<0$.

---

**NOTE:**

The singularity at $x=1$ is of order $(1-x)^{-1/2}$, and does not compromise the aforementioned analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry, I haven't understood your first step for p<0 and the origin of the "2" in the last one... Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure. I'll edit and add to the parts for which you would like some explanation.

Comment: @sunrise  OK.  I edited.  Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Yes! It's clear now! I'm not used to solve exercises in this way... :) A lot of thanks for your kindness!

Comment: You're most certainly welcome.  It was my pleasure.  And with practice, you will do fine.

Comment: Your claim $\log(1+x^p)/\sqrt{x^2-1} \geq 1/x$ is not true so this solution is not valid. A counter-example is found for example if $p=0.1$ and $x=2$.

Comment: @Winther Yes, you're correct.  I've modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Look at the large $x$ behaviour, look at cases $p \geq 0, p<0$.

Comment: Are you certain?  Look at $p=-1$.  The integrand is $\frac{\log(x+1)-\log x}{x}$.  Do you believe the integral of that function won't converge?

Comment: I see!! Sorry, you are right... it needs some more thinking.

Comment: No worry.  I'm not one of those down voters.